# How can I execute a SQL and Params from C#

Tags: sql-server

Given the following:

```
var sql = @"xxxxxxx";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
List<SqlParameter> parameterList = new List<SqlParameter>()
{
    new SqlParameter("@Title", SqlDbType.NVarChar) { Value = "Practice " + testNumber.ToString()},
    new SqlParameter("@ExamId", SqlDbType.Int) { Value = (examId == 0 ? DBNull.Value : (object)examId)},
    new SqlParameter("@TopicId", SqlDbType.Int) { Value = (testTopicId == 0 ? DBNull.Value : (object)testTopicId)},
};    
cmd.Parameters.AddRange(parameterList.ToArray());
```

How can I actually execute the cmd from my c# code? What I would like to understand is the relationship with my sql and the cmd variable and what function I should use to call this.

Note that in the past I have been using this:

```
int result = db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sql, parameters);
```

If someone could explain differences between a solution and this it would be much appreciated.

Comment: If using an IDbConnection directly, It's often easier to use [`connection.CreateCommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.createcommand(v=vs.110).aspx), as this already associates the command with a relevant connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me know if this doesn't fully answer your question, I'm not totally sure I know what you're asking, but here's my best:

For non-queries, that's easy:

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

For queries, as in those where you need to return rows, you'll need to [get a `SqlDataReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kcbe65k(v=vs.110).aspx). This isn't overly complicated, but I like to use a wrapper I wrote, just so I don't mess anything up, since it can get a little confusing. In essence, though:

```
using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        // handle the row
    }
}
```

Now, as for parameters, your code should be handling those as it is, so I'm not sure what you're looking for there.

Setting the command text can be done one of two ways: the constructor (`new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [table] WHERE title = @Title")`), or post-facto using the `CommandText` property (`cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [table] WHERE title = @Title"`). Those parameter names will be mapped to the parameters you've added.

By the way, you might find it easier to utilize `SqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue`, rather than the `List<>` you do.

Comment: Can you tell me where the SQL gets added? I have the cmd.Parameters.AddRange that adds the params but how's the SQL made into the command? Thanks